# UI does not update on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react native maps and on `componentDidMount()` asking user to enable their location.

```
componentDidMount() {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  RNAndroidLocationEnabler.promptForEnableLocationIfNeeded({ interval: 20000, fastInterval: 5000 })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);

      this.findingLocation();
    }).catch(err => {
    });
}
else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  this.findingLocation();
}
```

}

And in `findingLocation()` I am trying to get the current location of user like this

```
 findingLocation = () => {
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0043,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0034,
      }
    }, () => {
      console.warn(this.state.region);
    });
  },
  error => console.warn('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000 },
);
```

}

And in console I am getting lat long of current location.
But it does not reflect on UI sometimes .

UI code

```
<MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={styles.map}
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      zoomControlEnabled={true}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
    />
```

Libraries I am using are https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps for MAP & https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation for GEOLOCATION.

Help me please.
Where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many times and where do you call `findingLocation`, except in `componentDidMount`

Comment: only one time just in componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator in your setState function. As for why, read this article: https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  region: {
    ...prevState.region
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0043,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0034,
  }
}), () => {
  console.warn(this.state.region);
})
```