# Marker not moving on map even after rerendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am fetching coordinates from my database every 5 seconds, and my marker is dynamic, this is my render method

```
console.log('render'+this.state.driverLocation.latitude +' '+this.state.driverLocation.longitude);


    let marker = null;
    marker = <MapView.Marker title='This is you' coordinate={this.state.driverLocation } />;

 return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
          region={!this.state.locationChosen ? this.state.focusedLocation : null}
          style={styles.map}
          onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
          ref={ref => this.map = ref}
        >
          {marker}
     


        </MapView>
```

The log statement in render shows driverLocation changes every 5 sec as it should but the marker stays at the initial position (coordinates given while defining state).

Is there any problem with my code? Do I need to add something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61369667/10407485

Comment: Hey!! I already found the solution but thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that android relies only on the key to change in order to update the custom marker and it can be solved by assigning a random key to the marker every time there's a need for rerendering.
So, something like this:

```js
marker = <MapView.Marker 
title='This is you' 
coordinate={this.state.driverLocation}
 key={ this.GenerateRandomNumber() }
 } />;
```

While:

```js
GenerateRandomNumber=()=>
{
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
return RandomNumber;

}
```